# Android FileNotFoundException res/drawable-hdpi/scrollbar_handle_vertical.9.png

Tags: android, android-layout

The most significant user-reported crash for my app right now is below. It seems like the system cannot find the file res/drawable-hdpi/scrollbar_handle_vertical.9.png
The below example indicates the problem happens when drawing a webview, but it also happens for other activities in my app, all of which work fine most of the time.

I would think this is an android resource that I wouldn't need to worry about. But, just to test, I took the file from the sdk and placed it into my project drawable-hdpi folder for the latest release of my app. However, I still observer the crash reports in google play.

Any thoughts as to what could be happening?

I'm also not using progaurd right now, so no way that is stripping out files it shouldn't.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class com.android.internal.app.AlertController$RecycleListView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
at android.webkit.WebView$InvokeListBox.run(WebView.java:8308)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$RecycleListView.<init>(AlertController.java:703)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
... 14 more
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-hdpi/scrollbar_handle_vertical.9.png from drawable resource ID #0x0
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1714)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
at android.widget.AbsListView.<init>(AbsListView.java:630)
at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:230)
at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:226)
... 18 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable-hdpi/scrollbar_handle_vertical.9.png
at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method)
at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:405)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1706)
... 22 more
```

Comment: That file is from the [Android framework](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/scrollbar_handle_vertical.9.png). Maybe you can create a custom theme and include a replacement for `<item name="scrollbarThumbVertical">@android:drawable/scrollbar_handle_vertical</item>` to fix that error.

Comment: hello.  Any update on this error that might not have been posted?  I just started receiving this same problem and have no idea why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems likely that this resource is missing on one (or more devices). i.e. the build of Android on that device is missing this file. It would be interesting to see whether the issue is affecting very specific devices.

I expect the solution will be to use a drawable in your app itself (rather than rely on one in android) and make sure your one is referenced, not the one that is missing on certain devices.

You can use tools like BugSense to track issues like this to collect data on affected devices & platform versions. This is useful if you're unable to get this information from the Google Play Store reporting.

Comment: I have seen this error only on sgh-t959v devices running Android 2.2.1 on the T-Mobile network.

Comment: We've also seen the same crash, on exactly that device, it's reported as SGH T959V running 2.2.1.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue on the Froyo emulator in the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

One more case when this happens - when you use attribute/resource introduced in later android versions. There are some complex mappings attributes to indexes and when appt generates R.java it possibly can overlap some old ids and this very weird error occurs.

For me, the same error appeared when in view was set 
`android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`

  `selectableItemBackground` was introduced in api 11, but was launched at emulator with api 7.

So check your layouts for using some resources introduced later than your minSdkVersion. It can be checked at [R.java reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html)